# CRM 2013 :Same database as different organization

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create two CRM 2013 organizations using same CRM 2011 database.I can use differetn sql server database of course but when importing the database for the second time it gives error of this organization is already imported during importing new organization process.
Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore first the backup to a different DB name.

You can find a tutorial with screenshots here (are for 2011 but for 2013 should be similar the process):

http://msdynamics2011.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-copy-microsoft-crm-2011.html